# html zoom on mouse over

Tags: javascript, html, zooming, mouseover

I want to have a photo in a site, and when I mouse over, I want a little magnifier zoom effect.

Can I do this in html with canvas or something? javascript maybe?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas isn't supported by IE without third-party plug-ins. You'll want to do this in JavaScript. jQuery makes this very easy and clean. Bind handlers for the hover in / out events for the image element you want to zoom using `.hover()`. "Binding handlers" simply means you pass two functions to .hover() which will be executed when the user hovers in and out, respectively. These functions will use `animate()`, which you can simply pass a new size.

Have a look at the documentation for [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/). If you're totally new to jQuery, [check out the tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials).

Answer (score 3):

Enclose your photo in a div and add [Zoom](http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/) via CSS on hover. You may want to increase the z-index upon hover. You can add to the below CSS to make the zoomed photo look/style better. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, look out for some Jquery plugin which may accomplish the same thing in an elegant manner with less effort.

CSS:

```
#div-1 {
            position: absolute;
        }
#div-1.hover {
            position: absolute; zoom: 70%; border: solid 1px; z-index:10;
        }
```

Jquery/Javascript:

```
          <script type = "text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".div-1").onmouseover(function() {
    toggle_visibility('div-1');
})

function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if ($(e).hasClass("hover")) {
        $(e).removeClass("hover");
    } else {
        $($(e)).addClass("hover");
        $($(e)).attr({
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%"
        });
    }
}}); < /script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can show the image in a div as a background-image and change the position with a little javascript.

Here's a library with some examples: http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/demos.php

Comment: how would one go about making the zoom area circular using jQZoom?

Comment: @codecowboy: I have written a response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856381/how-can-i-customise-jquery-loupe-to-have-a-circular-lens/5856594#5856594

Comment: it would have been less confusing if you had put it here! But thanks :-)

Comment: @codecowboy: ah... my bad. I assumed it was also about jQZoom