# How can I customise jquery loupe to have a circular lens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loupe

I would appreciate the thoughts of any javascript / css ninjas on how I can customise:

https://github.com/jdbartlett/loupe/blob/master/jquery.loupe.js

To have a circular zoom area instead of rectangular one? There is an option to set a css class for the loupe.

Please note that this is a question about the library linked above. I have already googled for other libraries. I want to keep the js as small as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the developer of loupe.js:

you may want to look at chris iufer's loupe, which is only a bit
bigger than mine and includes a few samples that use css3 to achieve a
round loupe:

http://chrisiufer.com/loupe/sample.html

whereas mine uses an absolutely positioned image within a div, his
uses background-image on the div and background-position to move the
image, so css3 border-radius works.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the easiest way to do this is to use CSS3 border-radius, which is supported by the modern versions of all web-browsers (no IE lower than version 9).

If you have this in your javascript

```
$('selector').loupe({
    width: 150, // width of magnifier
    height: 150, // height of magnifier
    loupe: 'loupe' // css class for magnifier
});
```

Just put this in your css:

```
.loupe {
-webkit-border-radius: 150px;
-moz-border-radius: 150px;
border-radius: 150px;
}
```

... and all old versions of IE will just show a square, which is maybe OK in your case?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The loupe is a div without a border. I can add a border and get that to curve but the div containing the zoom area remains rectangular (and on top)

Comment: @codecowboy: Execute this bit of javascript with Firebug on the demo page and you'll see that it works in some of the examples: `jQuery('.zoomPup').css('-moz-border-radius', '150px')`. Link to the demos page: http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/demos.php

Comment: @codecowboy: The border-radius has nothing to do with the normal border, so you don't need to apply a border to your div. You can read about border-radius here: http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Comment: @WQoLpH this isnt a question about jqzoom

Comment: @codecowboy: my bad... the answer holds though. Fred Bergman his answer works just fine for jQzoom